# How to run the following scripts in cmd or powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm converting metastock data format into `CSV` using `atem64 converter`. Basically `atem64` is the exe file, `-o` is the output file, the directory at end of line is source directory. Now I want to automate this process rather than run them one by one in cmd. I figure I can use loop on this but I still don't know much about powershell, right now my focus is to finish the stockparser I program in Golang and our backend API that will use these data. But before I can even upload these to database, I need them in `CSV` format, can someone help me?

May be specify each source and corresponding output directory/file in another text file then run `atem64` through a loop?

```
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/Global FX.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/Global FX"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/Global Index.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/Global Index"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/HFRI.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/HFRI"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US AMEX.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/US AMEX"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NASDAQ.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NASDAQ"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NASDAQ ETF.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NASDAQ ETF"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NYSE.TXT" -f "-time,-openint" --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NYSE"



atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/Global FX Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/Global FX"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/Global Index Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/Global Index"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/HFRI Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/HFRI"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US AMEX Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/US AMEX"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NASDAQ Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NASDAQ"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NASDAQ ETF Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NASDAQ ETF"
atem64 -F, -o "./ATEM Convert Day/US NYSE Symbols.TXT" -s --ignore-master "./Download Day/US NYSE"
```

Comment: These command lines look perfectly fine for me. I guess you should wrap the `-F,` in quotes as well and it should run as intended.

Comment: you mean just put them in a file (bat? ps1?) then run that script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `.\` in front of every line and changing `-F,` into `-F","`
Although it would still be nice if I can do it using loops. Anyway, there are only a few lines so I guess that won't matter much